# Add column to a Dataset based on the value from Another Dataset

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset dsCustomer that have the customer details with columns

```
|customerID|idpt | totalAmount|
|customer1 | H1  |    250     |
|customer2 | H2  |    175     |
|customer3 | H3  |    4000    |
|customer4 | H3  |    9000    |
```

I have another dataset dsCategory that contains the category based on the amount sales

```
|categoryID|idpt | borne_min|borne_max|
|A         |  H2 | 0        |1000     |
|B         |  H2 | 1000     |5000     |
|C         |  H2 | 5000     |7000     |
|D         |  H2 | 7000     |10000    |
|F         |  H3 | 0        |1000     |
|G         |  H3 | 1000     |5000     |
|H         |  H3 | 5000     |7000     |
|I         |  H3 | 7000     |1000000  |
```

I would like to have a result that is taking the totalAmount of Customer and find the category.

```
|customerID|idpt |totalAmount|category|
|customer1 | H1  |   250     | null   |
|customer2 | H2  |   175     | A      |
|customer3 | H3  |   4000    | G      |
|customer4 | H3  |   9000    | I      |
```

```java
//udf 
public static Column getCategoryAmount(Dataset<Row> ds, Column amountColumn) {
        return ds.filter(amountColumn.geq(col("borne_min"))
                .and(amountColumn.lt(col("borne_max")))).first().getAs("categoryID");

    }

//code to add column to my dataset
dsCustomer.withColumn("category", getCategoryAmount(dsCategory , dsCustomer.col("totalAmount")));
```

How  can i pass the value of column from my dataset of customer to my UDF function

Because the error is showing that totalAmount is not contains in the category dataset

Question: How can i use Map to for each row in the dsCustomer i should go and check they value in dsCategory.

I have tried to join the 2 tables but it is working because the dsCustomer should maintain the same records just added the calulated column picked from dsCategory.

`` caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`totalAmount`' given input columns: [categoryID,borne_min,borne_max];;
'Filter (('totalAmount>= borne_min#220) && ('totalAmount < borne_max#221)) ``

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the two datasets. `withColumn` only allows modifications of the same Dataset.

## UPDATE

I did not have time before to explain in detail what I mean. This is what I was trying to explain. You *can* join two dataframes. In your case you need a left join to preserve rows which don't have a matching category.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

cust = [
    ('customer1', 'H1', 250), 
    ('customer2', 'H2', 175), 
    ('customer3', 'H3', 4000),
    ('customer4', 'H3', 9000)
]

cust_df = spark.createDataFrame(cust, ['customerID', 'idpt', 'totalAmount'])

cust_df.show()

cat = [
    ('A', 'H2', 0   , 1000),
    ('B', 'H2', 1000, 5000),
    ('C', 'H2', 5000, 7000),
    ('D', 'H2', 7000, 10000),
    ('F', 'H3', 0   , 1000),
    ('G', 'H3', 1000, 5000),
    ('H', 'H3', 5000, 7000),
    ('I', 'H3', 7000, 1000000)
]

cat_df = spark.createDataFrame(cat, ['categoryID', 'idpt', 'borne_min', 'borne_max'])

cat_df.show()

cust_df.join(cat_df, 
             (cust_df.idpt == cat_df.idpt) & 
             (cust_df.totalAmount >= cat_df.borne_min) & 
             (cust_df.totalAmount <= cat_df.borne_max)
            , how='left') \
.select(cust_df.customerID, cust_df.idpt, cust_df.totalAmount, cat_df.categoryID) \
.show()
```

### Output

```
+----------+----+-----------+
|customerID|idpt|totalAmount|
+----------+----+-----------+
| customer1|  H1|        250|
| customer2|  H2|        175|
| customer3|  H3|       4000|
| customer4|  H3|       9000|
+----------+----+-----------+

+----------+----+---------+---------+
|categoryID|idpt|borne_min|borne_max|
+----------+----+---------+---------+
|         A|  H2|        0|     1000|
|         B|  H2|     1000|     5000|
|         C|  H2|     5000|     7000|
|         D|  H2|     7000|    10000|
|         F|  H3|        0|     1000|
|         G|  H3|     1000|     5000|
|         H|  H3|     5000|     7000|
|         I|  H3|     7000|  1000000|
+----------+----+---------+---------+

+----------+----+-----------+----------+
|customerID|idpt|totalAmount|categoryID|
+----------+----+-----------+----------+
| customer1|  H1|        250|      null|
| customer3|  H3|       4000|         G|
| customer4|  H3|       9000|         I|
| customer2|  H2|        175|         A|
+----------+----+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: I can't join the 2 datasets because they don't have the relation key.
If i just join them , it will result with the cartesian results

Comment: You should join on `amountColumn.geq(col("borne_min"))
                .and(amountColumn.lt(col("borne_max")))`

Comment: i have updated the problem. i am posting it here because the solution to join is not working for 2 tables.

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer. Upvote if you like it.

Comment: @brunelFabriceTouopiTouopi very happy it works for you! Consider marking as _accepted answer_ if you indeed accept it :)